# Broken HTTPS after changing SSL certificate on site

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I purchased a new SSL certificate, and want to switch my site over to it. I know that after your browser trusts one ssl certificate for a given host it will appear as invalid if the host is spitting out a different certificate than expected, so I haven't migrated my site to the new cert yet, except for one A record.

Is there any way to transfer the trust of the previous cert into the new one so that it doesn't appear as invalid?

Edit:
Looks like everyone was right. After restarting my computer the certificate no longer shows up as a broken red lock and the error message that said `The page is insecure (broken HTTPS)` no longer appears. So moral of the story is that the certificate was still valid and I jumped the gun in thinking it was caching the old one.

Comment: only if certificate pinning is in use. default is for browsers to accept ANY valid certificate, whether or not it's a "real" cert or a self-signed one that you told the browser is "ok".

Comment: Are you familiar with Certificate Authorities(CA)? Typically browsers trust a set of CAs and any certificate signed by them will be accepted as long as it hasn't been explicitly revoked.

Comment: I'm not using certificate pinning to the best of my knowledge.The cert is from COMODO, as was the old one. Would I need to maybe add something from the old certificate to the new certs bundle? To be clear, the certificate is accepted and valid, but the browser still shows the page as insecure.

The subdomain sub2.sub1.mysite.com was under the wildcard cert for *.mysite.com, which was an invalid cert name since it wasn't covered. Now I've purchased one for *.sub1.mysite.com and since a certificate has already been accepted it is considered insecure.

Comment: What does https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html have to say about your domain & cert?

Comment: It gave me an 'A', but no details

Comment: What is particular error message?

Comment: The https lock is red, the site doesn't ask for me to accept the cert or anything though. When inspecting it, it says something along the lines of 'the page is insecure (broken https)'

Answer (score 0):

Is this in a particular browser? I'm not aware of browsers 'caching' certificate fingerprints by default.

You should be able to just change the cert and it should be accepted, provided the configuration is correct.

If you don't get a full error, just a red 'https', then that means that the cert is valid, but there's an issue with the config. It may be the key length? Or mixed content?

Comment: I'm using chrome. I don't think I have any special settings for caching certs, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**Scenario 1:**

If you have apache hosting, you should add CA bundle for each certificate configuration.

If you have IIS hosting, Comodo CA bundles are pre-installed in all Microsoft OS.

**Scenario 2:**

You should bind/configure correct SSL for each sub-domain.

SSL certificate issued for *.mysite.com should be configured for

> - sub1.mysite.com
> - sub2.mysite.com

SSL certificate issued for *.sub1.mysite.com should be configured for

> - xyz.sub1.mysite.com
> - abc.sub1.mysite.com

You can use this certificate for sub1.mysite.com also.

**Scenario 3:**

If you have domain and sub-domains configuration like

> - abc.sub1.mysite.com
> - app.sub1.mysite.com
> - abc.sub2.mysite.com
> - xyz.sub2.mysite.com
> - abc.sub3.mysite.com
> - any.sub3.mysite.com

This requirement can be fulfilled with Comodo Multi-Domain Wildcard SSL certificate https://www.ssl2buy.com/comodo-multi-domain-wildcard-ssl.php

This product can secure below examples in single SSL certificate and convenient to manage single SSL for all wildcard domains.

> - *.mysite.com
> - *.sub1.mysite.com
> - *.sub2.mysite.com
> - *.sub3.mysite.com

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed response. Hopefully it helps someone in the future. The configuration is all good. I'm using an AWS load balancer to handle the cert and route 53 to manage the sub-domains.